# Difference between flex sensor's different sizes

Tags: arduino, android-sensors, arduino-uno

I would like to know that is there any difference between using flex sensor of different sizes? I mean in terms of resistance ?

Comment: longer = more precise, for (hopefully) obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Length of a flex sensor and it's resistance are not related. You can have flex sensors of the same length with different resistances or same resistance and different lengths.